# how to create persistence volume using mesos DCOS and marathon

Tags: volume, persistent, dcos

While using the following command:

```
$ dcos marathon app add example.json
```

I receive the output `Error: Object is not valid`

**example.json**

```
{
"id": "es-cluster",
"env": {
    "MARATHON_URL": "http://127.0.0.1:8080",
    "APP_ID": "es-cluster",
    "ELASTICSEARCH_CLUSTER_NAME": "CLUSTERNAME"
},
"container": {
    "type": "DOCKER",
    "volumes": [
      {
            "containerPath": "data",
            "mode": "RW",
            "persistent": {
                "size": 1000
            }
      }
    ],
    "docker": {
        "image": "some/dockerImage",
        "network": "BRIDGE",
        "portMappings": [{
            "containerPort": 9200
        }, {
            "containerPort": 9300
        }]
    }
},
"cpus": 0.5,
"mem": 1024,
"instances": 2
}
```

If I remove the volume block (or keep it empty), it works fine.

Also running it with the volume block directly with Marathon works perfect.

How can I create an app with persistent volume using DCOS?

Comment: I think we need some more info here. The Marathon app spec is valid, I checked that. You say it works 'directly with Marathon' which I interpret as: via the Marathon UI? If so, you can try the following: in the right upper corner of the `New Application` dialog you see a `JSON Mode` switch. Enter your details, switch to JSON and save the result in `example.json` and tell us what you see.

Comment: can be found here:
http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=51648903778285053855

Again it works threw marathon but DCOS still throws: "Error: Object is not valid"

Answer (score 5):

Got it to work.

Tried to POST the example.json using Marathon api *http://marathon-ip:8080/v2/apps* and got the following message:

> {"message":"Object is not
>   valid","details":[{"path":"/value/upgradeStrategy","errors":["got 1.0,
>   expected 0.5 or less","got 1.0, expected
>   0.0"]},{"path":"/value/isResident","errors":["must be false"]}]}

I then created the app (with volume) using Marathon UI and copied the json for reference. I noticed that marathon adds this block:

```
  "upgradeStrategy": {
    "minimumHealthCapacity": 0.5,
    "maximumOverCapacity": 0
  }
```

after adding this block to my original example.json (posted in the question) it worked.